# Is there any Azure based service similar to IBM Watson Knowledge Studio?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson, azure-cognitive-services

I tried to find some Azure service similar to IBM Watson Knowledge Studio but I failed. I'm looking for something I can train to analyze texts and retrieving entities, relations between entities and entities related sentiments.

Do you know if there is anything in Azure I could use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is remote similarity between Azure Language Understanding (LUIS) and IBM Watson Knowledge Studio (WKS), but they are not substitutes.

The notable differences:

1. LUIS is for building chatbots - conversations with utterance data. WKS is for general unstructured text, usually much larger in volume than utterances. In this respect, LUIS is competing with IBM Conversation service, not with WKS and the IBM Watson services that run the WKS custom models - Watson Natural Language Understanding and Watson Discovery.
   Because LUIS is built for processing utterances, it has much lower limits, compared to WKS. For example, LUIS limits the input text to 500 characters, while WKS processes text of up to 40,000 characters. LUIS also limits the Simple entities to 30, which may be ok for processing targeted utterances, but not for building high quality model for processing large documents and complex domains.
2. LUIS supports only customization of Entity Type mentions (in various forms, like Simple, Hierarchical, Composite, RegEx, List,.. - very similar to the WKS Entity types). WKS (and the runtime services that use the WKS custom models), on the other hand, supports Entity Relations - an important feature that helps you extract insights from the client-specific corpus that you cannot do with Entity mentions alone.
3. LUIS supports only a fraction of the languages that WKS supports. And the LUIS language support is partial - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-supported-languages
4. LUIS, similarly to IBM Conversation service, is a runtime NLP service that allows customization in its tooling. WKS, on the other hand, is a stand alone customization SaaS offering, that was specifically designed to organize a team of domain subject matter experts (SME) and cognitive solution developers to transfer the SME domain knowledge into the custom model that is then deployed to and used by IBM Watson runtime services, like Natural Language Understanding and Discovery. In other words, while LUIS and IBM Conversion provide tooling for customizing the solution directly, WKS provides a separate environment with built-in methodology for managing customization projects and for annotation skill building.
5. LUIS, to my understanding, is offered as a multi-tenant public service. WKS is offered in both multi-tenant and isolated configurations. In that respect, WKS is suitable not only for the general public, but also for projects with sensitive client data.

In conclusion, there's no WKS equivalent (substitute) that I'm aware of. LUIS may be considered as the Azure alternative to IBM Conversation service, if your solution is built in Azure, but LUIS is not a substitute for IBM Watson Knowledge Studio.
So, it's very important to consider your use case (application domain), when choosing on which platform to build your solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Azure AI gallery? One common approach is to customise the solutions there for your particular requirements. Here's [a search of all text-related items](https://gallery.azure.ai/browse), which you can for example refine to be Microsoft content only.

I'm not aware of a single service that maps directly; the [Text Analytics API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics) for example just does language and phrase detection and sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Luis.ai...should do what you need.